# Flagging and Community Wiki

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A few weeks ago, the community wiki check box was removed, and only moderators can now convert a question to CW. Users should flag a post to notify the mods.

However, I noted that it requires 16 flags to inform a mod. In my opinion, this is way too high. For instance, I flagged one of my own questions, but it's not CW yet since I think not enough users have flagged it as such, and therefore no mod is informed.

I wanted to know if you share the same opinion with me? Isn't it better to have a separate mechanism (like "flag as CW") which has a lower threshold?

If I receive positive opinions, I'll ask for it on SO meta.

Comment: @Sadeq: Do you have a reference for the 16 flags threshold?

Comment: @Hsien-Chih: Trying to flag a post shows [this message](http://s1.bild.me/bilder/311010/8555469flag.PNG). The number 16 is there.

Comment: @Sadeq: I guess the answer by @Jeff says everything ;)

Comment: @Hsien-Chih: Yeah ;)

Comment: @Sadeq: Currently it only receives 5 answers, much lesser than the [normal requirement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741) (30) to become a CW. The question is so good, and you worth those points :)

Comment: @Sadeq, I agree with Hsien-Chih Chang, it is a good question and it has only 5 answers, there is not any reason for it to be CW IMHO (and I like that we have non-CW high-vote questions :). If you still think that it needs to be CW, just flag it.

Comment: @Hsien-Chih, @Kaveh: Thanks. The reason I wanted to make it CW is there's not a single answer for it. All answers are very good and each point to a different aspect. Yet I like the idea of non-CW high-vote questions :). So, let's keep it as is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It only takes one "flag for moderator attention" to notify site moderators.

I think what you are referring to is the count of the number of flags you have remaining. You get 10 moderator flags per day plus one additional flag for every 1k of rep you have, thus you can flag 16 times in a given UTC day.

Hover your mouse over the number and it will explain.

Comment: My bad. I misunderstood the purpose.